# Binding didnt work with PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf

im trying to bind a property to a TEXTBLOCK in SplashScreen with xaml. The textblock should display the content of a property. The class Handler have the property "Shares", in the xaml code of the splashscreen i wrote this code:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="DXApplication3.WaitScreen"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"   
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DXApplication3"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DataContext="{x:Static dx:SplashScreenViewModel.DesignTimeData}">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:Handler x:Key="Shares"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="455" Width="859">
    <Grid x:Name="Splash" Width="450" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0">
        <Grid x:Name="Back">
            <Border Background="Black" CornerRadius="3" Opacity="0.15"/>
            <Border CornerRadius="2" Margin="-200,2,-201,-257" Background="White"/>
        </Grid>
        <Image x:Name="Logotype" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Source="../DXSplashScreen/DTILogo.png" Stretch="None"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="0,24,0,51" Width="253" >
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="-413" Y="-55"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <Grid x:Name="Content_Area" Margin="12">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <dx:WaitIndicator Content="Loading..." DeferedVisibility="true" Margin="0,120,0,-52" Grid.RowSpan="4">
                <dx:WaitIndicator.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="Please Wait" FontSize="20"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="ShareAnalyzer is running..."/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dx:WaitIndicator.ContentTemplate>
            </dx:WaitIndicator>
            <DockPanel x:Name="Footer" Grid.Row="3" Margin="-181,115,205,-91">
                <TextBlock x:Name="TextHeader" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Analyzed shares" Opacity="1" Foreground="#FF2D2D2D" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,2,0,-2" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform/>
                            <TranslateTransform X="2" Y="28"/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock x:Name="SharesHeader" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Shares}, Path=Shares, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Opacity="1" Foreground="#FF2D2D2D" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,-87,1" FontSize="13.333" Width="124">
                    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
```

I binded the textblock named (SharesHeader) to the property Shares in Handler.cs

```
 class Handler : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _shares;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public string Shares
    {
        get { return _shares; }
        set
        {
            _shares = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Shares");
        }
    }
    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

The SplashScreen should be starting wenn i click the button in the MainWindow.cs. But the problem is, after the sart the textblock in the splashscreen is emty.

can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Try to set your class as public and instead of using Text={StaticResource...} use Text={Binding Shares}

Comment: i tried it, but it still not working..

Comment: How are you are populating the Shares property ? In the Handler class' constructor, assign some value to Shares property, and run .

Comment: I tried to set some values to Handler.Shares in the MainWindow.xaml.cs like this

Comment: And this line is not needed :  PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = PropertyChanged; and in next line change p to Capital case P in propertyChanged(...).

Comment: private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {           
            DXSplashScreen.Show<WaitScreen>();
            handler = new Handler();
            handler.Shares = "Test 1";
        }

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the event it self

Comment: Your line `PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;` should be outside of the null check and the null check should be `if (propertyChanged != null)` using the local vairable. The entire reason you make the copy is so the null check can never become invalid between the time you check for null and the time you call the delegate. By making a local copy before the `if` you "freze" its value so if it is null it will always be null and if it is not null it will never become null during the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are binding to a static resource (which you named `Shares`), but are changing a different property (according to the code in your comment, one named `handler`).

So you are defining this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <local:Handler x:Key="Shares"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And binding to it as:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="SharesHeader" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Shares}, Path=Shares, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" /*... */ >
```

But changing this:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
   DXSplashScreen.Show<WaitScreen>(); 
   handler = new Handler(); 
   handler.Shares = "Test 1"; 
}
```

So instead of creating a new instance, like you are doing now, use the instance you already created via XAML, and change its `Shares` property, like:

```
(this.Resources["Shares"] as Handler).Shares = "Test 1";
```

Where `this` is your window (or `UserControl`, or wherever you have defined the resource on) object. Check nulls as you see appropiate.

## Bonus

As others stated in the comments, the whole point of copying the event variable to a local one is "freezing" it so if other threads modify the event between your null check and the actual calling, you'll be working on an unmodified copy.

So your:

```
if (PropertyChanged != null)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
    propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Should be:

```
PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
if (propertyChanged != null)
{
    propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

However, if you are using C# 6 (Visual Studio 2015), you can use the null conditional operator, that will do the same for you, and change it to simply:

```
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```